# AngularJS - Converting timestamp date format to javascript format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, timestamp

I want to show in a view of an angular project a human friendly date format, and I saw that angular has a filter to do so, but the input date needs to have a certain format.

The desired output format to be seen in the view is the following: "dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

Currently, I have on a Database the following timestamp format:

"2016-08-15 12:34:34"

How can I format this type of timestamp so that angular can intepret it  and format it as desired?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: To be clear that desired format would render you something like `Monday/August/2016 06:00:00`, you sure you want that?

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake on the day.. Let me edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the date to a javascript date and then use the date filter in Angular to show it in the format you want (if you can't use the date filter on the date from your database directly).

You could do this as a filter to make it easier:

```
myApp.filter('formatted', function() {
  return function(value) {
    return new Date(value);
  }
});
```

In your html you could then add this filter before the date filter:

`Filter: {{ vm.dateToFormat | formatted | date: 'dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss' }}`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the inline filter:

Example:

```
<span>{{vm.Date | date: 'dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'}}</span>
```

EDIT: To be clear, you post doesn't clarify if that timestamp is a string or not, so you may have to parse it accordingly. I see the other posters just assumed it was a string.

Answer (score 0):

If Angular is having trouble parsing the string from the database on its own you could just use JavaScript `Date.parse("2016-08-15 12:34:34")` to return you a date that Angular will interpret properly.